# Populate Mongoose Document from multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a way to populate documents beyond a document or the ref parameter.

```
 const LibarySchema = new Schema({
     books:[{
         book: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId},
         bookType: { type: String }
        }, { _id: false}]
 });

 const BookType1Schema = new Schema({  
    bookType: {
      type: String,
      default: 'lecture'
    },
 });
 const BookType2Schema = new Schema({
     bookType: {
      type: String,
      default: 'assingment'
    },
 });
```

This is an example of a similar project model, I am working on with 3 models. The first model hold all the information of the library books while the other models are the type of books. So during insertion of new book to the library array the bookType is added to know the collection to look for.
So my question is, is there anyway during population to check for the bookType and choose the right collection to find the book. 
Also i am open for suggestion on the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just simply have a single schema for the thing you asks. Don't make unnecessary schema and make you collections bulky.. It will not be good when querying with tons of data when the system grows ...

Don't use separate schemas for storing just the types just make a single library book schema and use that to find the book you wan to find